# How do I use Google Analytics for community members?

Tags: google-analytics

If I have a blog where there are 20 users and I want to track their traffic with GA, which is the best solution here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [Custom Variables](http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/tracking/gaTrackingCustomVariables.html)

Comment: Thanks! Byt I dont get the "index", must it be betweed 1-5? How come? What does that track?

Oh and also, Do i need to track ALL of my members to my single google account? Seems kind of messy for me.. :/ Or how do I separeate the members from each others? So I use the "index" parameter or "name" parameter